# my ajax php contact form is not redirecting to desired page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, contact-form

i have a contact form on my website, which ive already used before on a different site. i just copied and paste it and changed the required info. it works perfectly fine on the first site but on the second site it wont redirect to the page i want it to. the details from the contact form are being sent to my email and everything works fine on that end but wont redirect to the thank you page. 
i checked the syntax of one compared to the other to see if there are any differences and there are none, its seems like the processis getting stuck at the "echo" stage:

```
//Executes if mail sent
        if ( $mail ) {
            echo 'AA';
            //Executes if autorespond equals to yes
            if( $autorespond == "yes") {
                include_once("autoresponde.php");

            }
        }
```

because i get a page saying AA, and it stops there.

what can this be a result of?
(if any more syntax is needed tell me and ill post it) 
thank you!

Comment: it could be that your $autorespond is not yes, or that your file autoresponde.php doesnt exist
add error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors',1); to top of file, and do echo of $autorespond

Comment: check whether output buffering is enabled (php_value output_buffering On in php.ini or .htaccess) - if it isn't then php won't be able to write the redirect headers because you have already sent output

Comment: first of all, echo your $autorespond value, to make sure it outputs what you want. Then, if you are trying to redirect if the condition is true, why use include_once and not redirect directly?

Answer (score 0):

Is that redirecting script placed inside "autoresponde.php", if Yes, then just test `<?php echo "Im here".$autorespond;?>` before the if condition.